# At what pressure does the helium undergo phase transition at room temperature?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, pressure, phase-transition, gas, inert-gases

At what pressure does the helium undergo phase transition at room temperature?

I can not find phase diagram at room temperature.

Answer (score 3):

From [Chemicool](http://www.chemicool.com/elements/helium-facts.html)

At normal atmospheric pressure helium does not solidify. At 25 atmospheres of pressure helium is a solid at 0.95 K. As the pressure rises, the temperature at which solid helium exists also rises. Helium can be made solid at room temperature if the pressure rises to about 114 thousand atmospheres: that is a pressure of 1.67 million psi, or 834 tons per square inch. This is over 100 times greater than the pressure at the oceans’ deepest point, the Challenger Deep, which is almost seven miles deep (10 916 meters).

[image]

I cannot find a phase diagram at room temperature either.